# Five from three -- what am I?

Tags: wordplay, letters

Another puzzle in the tradition of five from four:

I am three, but my second can be any of the five.

- My first is placed above you.
- My second believes itself normative.
- My third is of wild popularity.
- My fourth is alluring and desirable.
- My fifth can be all around you.

Comment: +1 for gaining the confidence to post after our discussion on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25734/60644) - well done :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> H_T

And we obtain the explanations by

> Placing the nth vowel in the space

My first is placed above you.

> HAT

My second believes itself normative.

> HET (referring to hetero-normativity, I think)

My third is of wild popularity.

> HIT

My fourth is alluring and desirable.

> HOT

My fifth can be all around you.

> HUT

I am three, but my second can be any of the five.

> Three letters long but the second letter can be any of the five vowels.