# A word exercise : Same consonants and five vowels

Tags: wordplay, no-computers

Can you think of 5 different 5-letter words which use the same 4 consonants and each word includes one separate vowel?

You must use all 5 vowels. In all 5 words, the 4 consonants and one vowel must be in the same location.

For example the five words could look like

123A4   123E4   123I4   123O4   123U4

Or 1A234   1E234   1I234   1O234   1U234

1, 2, 3, and 4 are separate consonants but every word must use the same 4 at the same locations.

Proper nouns are OK, although a solution without them would be great.

I found at least 1 solution.

Bonus : Is there a sixth word which uses the pseudo-vowel Y??

No computers please, although you can check your word in a reputable dictionary.

Comment: Just to be clear, if two of the consonants are the same letter, does this invalidate the answer?

Comment: I found that to be easier than the 4 seperate consonants. There are more solutions with only 3 consonants in a 5 letter word

Comment: You should probably clarify that you want English words.  Or will you accept words from other languages that use the Roman alphabet (and how do diacritical marks fit in)?  Also, how about three consonants and a (fixed) vowel; e.g., [(ROT13) znffrf/zrffrf/zvffrf/zbffrf/zhffrf](http://www.decode.org/?q=znffrf/zrffrf/zvffrf/zbffrf/zhffrf), as [identified by Uri Zarfaty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/10722/19765#10725).

Comment: l remember seeing a group of words like this, but one of them is a surname, and the words each have six letters instead of five.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> STACK - a vertical pile
>  STECK - a [surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steck)
>  STICK - a small piece of broken tree
>  STOCK - a quantity of items
>  STUCK - an unfortunate result of licking a metal pole in winter

Let's go ahead and use Google to fill in the blanks on this one (sorry, no-computers tag.):

> STALE - the worst kind of bread
>  STELE - the core of a plant's stem and root (thanks, Google)
>  STILE - a flow-control mechanism on gates or fences
>  STOLE - what Maui did with the Heart of Te Fiti
>  STULE - a surname (thanks, Google)
>  STYLE - what you forgo when you wear socks with sandals

Even more Googling this time:

> The entire list of words with only Y and no repeated letters is: byrls, crypt, glyph, hwyls, hymns, lymph, lynch, myths, nymph, psych, rynds, sylph, synch, synth, wynds.
>
>  I'm not sure that any of these can use all five vowels. B_RLS, M_THS, R_NDS, and W_NDS look the best.

Comment: Anything with Y???

Comment: I had to use Google to assist in the verification of E and U, but rot13(fg_yr) would fit all 5+1.

Comment: Your second answer looks really good, although rot13(gur ynfg yrggre vf abg n pbafbanag nf erdhverq ol gur dhrfgvba)...

Comment: Yeah, I know. Also Google. :)

Comment: Also, excuse you, socks and sandals are apparently perfectly reasonable now (although people tell me I can never pull that look off!)

Answer (score 10):

I found one

> BLIND (not seeing)
>  BLOND (hair)
>  BLAND (lacking of something)
>  BLEND (like in a blender...)
>  BLUND (someone who doesn't accept defeat)
>  I am not so sure of BLUND as it isn't in a dictionnary.

And another one with almost the same letters

> BINDS (links)
>  BONDS (money related)
>  BANDS (music groups)
>  BENDS (Decompression sickness)
>  BUNDS (money related - a debt)

Comment: Blund is iffy @Untitpoi

Comment: @DEEM I agree, maybe you should not put the whole word in a comment to avoid spoiler! just saying "the word with U".

Comment: Your second E word: It's a pretty common term for anyone that is familiar with scuba diving.

Comment: For 'E':  or as in 'The board ____ when I stand on it"  

For 'U':  you accidentally copied you def from 'O'  

Otherwise this looks like a winning answer

Comment: Changing the first letter of your 2nd solution to "F" results in another valid solution.

Comment: @slvrbld: What? FA___ and FO___ aren’t words!

Comment: @PeregrineRook both of them can be found in some of the online dictionaries I checked. Definitely no commonly used words though ;)

Answer (score 5):

New one

> **P_CKS**
>  PACKS - packs of wolves, packs of cards, ...
>  PUCKS - the black ice hockey disks
>  PECKS - what birds do
>  PICKS - you need to be lucky with these to win the lottery
>  POCKS - you surely don't want these

Another one (one duplicate consonant)

> **B_LLS**
>  BILLS - I wish I didn't know what these were...
>  BALLS - Those round things
>  BELLS - They can make a lot of noise
>  BULLS - Animals
>  BOLLS - a "boll" is the "rounded seed capsule of plants such as cotton or flax".

Comment: 4 seperate consonents @slvrbid.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Overlooked that constraint. I'll try to look for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have one:

> CHACK - (of a bird) make a harsh call
>  CHECK - a form of payment / make sure of something
>  CHICK - a baby bird
>  CHOCK - a wedge or block placed against a wheel or rounded object, to prevent it from moving
>  CHUCK - throw / type of steak

Comment: The four consonants are required to be different, if I'm reading the question correctly.

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't think you are:  "1, 2, 3, and 4 are separate consonants but every word must use the same 4 at the same locations."

Answer (score 3):

> STANG - by a bee?
>  STENG - the mast next above a lower mast and topmost in a fore-and-aft rig
>  STING - by a bee?
>  STONG - An area of land equivalent to a quarter of an acre.
>  STUNG - by a bee?

Comment: I'm not certain "stang" is a word.

Comment: I know a fellow who had the last name using the 'a' variant.

Answer (score 2):

> B*tch

The uses are:

> **Batch** - as in a batch of cookies.
>  **Bitch** - a female dog...
>  **Botch** - to mess something up.
>  **Butch** - someone considered masculine.

And my favorite:

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: I think we'll need additional proof that that last one is actually a word. To me it looks like just a phonetic mis-spelling of one of your other words.

Comment: I dunno why the downvotes. I also like that favourite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one:

> Craps - A game of dice
> Creps - Informal name of training shoe
> Crips - Disabled people
> Crops - Cultivated plants that is grown as food
> Crups - Mythical being (dog with a forked tail)

Answer (score 0):

I (almost) have one!

> Last - coming after all others in time or order
>  Lest - with the intention of preventing
>  List - number of connected items or names
>  Lost - unable to find one's way
>  Lust - very strong sexual desire

Comment: 5 Letter words only @Yuca. But this was very good

Comment: dang, I forgot about that!